# Did the Episode "Snatch" really end with an ebay auction?

Tags: space-ghost-coast-to-coast

The ending of the Season 6 episode *Snatch* ends with a clip of a guy in colonial dress and text on the screen reading

> Bid on the "Space Ghost Ending" at ebay.com

It was mentioned that bidding would start at $7 and whoever won would get this special ending.

Did this really happen?  If so, how much did it end up auctioning for?

Answer (score 3):

Wow, apparently this did really happen. According to [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0706092/trivia/?ref_=tt_ql_trv):

> As for the eBay ending, viewers have wondered who bought the ending
> and what is on it. As of 2018, nobody has come forward as to what the
> ending contained nor have they uploaded it online. The producers of
> the show have never said what the original ending contained either.

According to [Lost Media Wiki](https://lostmediawiki.com/Space_Ghost_Coast_to_Coast_%22Snatch%22_Ending_(lost_script;_1999)#cite_note-2):

> It ended up being sold to an unknown die-hard fan who supposedly ended
> up bidding over $1000 for it[2](https://lostmediawiki.com/Space_Ghost_Coast_to_Coast_%22Snatch%22_Ending_(lost_script;_1999)#cite_note-2), and has never resurfaced in any form,
> official or unofficial.

LMW apparently has a screenshot of the auction.
There was also a discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/spaceghost/comments/elmymh/so_whos_got_the_secret_ending_to_snatch/).